# After updating single element, updated element shows twice in my UI, spot it came from and spot it was dragged to

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have the main screen of my app, where there are many different sections. The user can drag an `element` from section to section.

The problem I'm having is that once a user drags and drops an element into a new section (which hits the server with the updated info), the element is showing twice, once in the place that it came **from** and once in the place that it was dragged **to**.

Upon refreshing my app, it only shows in the place it was dragged to, which is correct.

I think the issue lies somewhere in my `recieveElement` reducer, which is hit after the update from the server.

Would love some help in debugging this. Thanks!

```
   case 'receiveElement':
        const elementId = `${action.element.id}`;

        // don't add, duplicate
        const newState = {...state}; // copy old state
        delete newState[elementId]; // delete the item from the object

        const newVisibleElementIds = newState.visibleElements.filter(id => id !== elementId); // remove item from visible elements
        const newUnplacedElementIds = newState.unplacedElements.filter(id => id !== elementId);

        return {
            ...newState,
            elementsMap: {
                ...newState.elementsMap,
                [elementId]: action.element,
            },
            visibleElements: [...newVisibleElementIds, elementId],
            unplacedElements: [...newUnplacedElementIds],
        };
```

In my `SkyElement` react object, I have the following, which is what hits the server before the reducer is hit

```
endDrag(props, monitor) {
        if (monitor.didDrop()) {
            const result = monitor.getDropResult();
        if (result.sectorId) {
            const obj = { id: props.id, sectorId: result.sectorId, slotId: result.slotId };

            props.dispatch(requestUpdateElement(obj));
        }
    }
},
```

Comment: Is the newVisibleElements array correct after dragging? Also what does the code snippet look like where you're making the async call?

Comment: yes, `newVisibleElementIds` is correct after the filter happens

Comment: So then are you re-rendering the view somehow somewhere in your code?

Comment: My understanding was that when the redux store was updated, the app would re-render all of my components. Is that not correct?

Comment: console.logging most of the values, they seem fine. There aren't duplicate ids in `newVisibleElementIds` for example